# Vue warning when accessing nested object

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am not sure why I get a Vue warning when accessing nested object.

```
{{ user.area.name }}
```

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Just accessing the object has no warning.

```
{{ user.name }}
```

Any advice?

Comment: What's the exact code you're using and the exact text of the warning?

Comment: ah yes, updated warning as above.

Comment: How / where is `user` populated with data?

Comment: Make sure you have `area` in `user` object (user.area is undefined)

Comment: In this context. `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` means that `user.area` is undefined.

Comment: area is included in user object and displaying area name is working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Totally guessing here but lets see if I'm right...

Say you've got something like this in your component / Vue instance `data` initialiser...

```js
data () {
  return {
    user: {}
  }
}
```

and you then populate that object asynchronously, eg

```js
mounted () {
  setTimeout(() => { // setTimeout is just an example
    this.user = {
      ...this.user,
      area: {
        name: 'foo'
      }
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

If your template has

```html
{{ user.area.name }}
```

when it initially renders **before** the asynchronous task has completed, you will be attempting to access the `name` property of `area` which is undefined.

Example ~ http://jsfiddle.net/tL1xbmoj/

---

Your options are...

1. Initialise your data with a structure that won't cause errors

   ```js
   data () {
     return {
       user: {
         area: { 
           name: null 
         } 
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   Example ~ http://jsfiddle.net/tL1xbmoj/1/
2. Use conditional rendering to prevent the error

   ```html
   <span v-if="user.area">{{ user.area.name }}</span>
   ```

   Example ~ http://jsfiddle.net/tL1xbmoj/2/

Comment: Hi, just as a side note from me as I just ran into that issue... I had to push a few values to the data object. I ended up with that "undefined" error. I then just moved it form the mounted() hook ot the created() hook (which makes sense as then the template is not rendered) and the issue was solved...

Answer (score 0):

Your `user` doesn't contain an `area`, so when you try to read that, it's `undefined`. You're not allowed to use the `.` operator on things that are `undefined`, so when you do `.name` on that, you get the error that you got.

Comment: area is included in user object and displaying area name is working. just don't want to see warning.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a ternary operator `{{ user.area ? user.area.name : "" }}`