# Vue JS 2 - dynamic array

Tags: vuejs2

I understand with Vue JS 2, you have to declare reactive properties upfront.
However, just wondering how would you do a rest call if the child objects appear depending on a few other conditions. For example:

```
"abc": {
        "tests": [
        {
          "a1": "xxxx",
          "result": null,
          "selected": false,
          "comment": null
        } ...
        ]
}
```

Now in this example, what happens if the tests are empty (`(null)`)  in some circumstances?
eg: if you bind it using the v-model `xx.xx.abc.tests[1].selected` - This wont work as `tests[1]` is null.

So I tried using Vue.set in mounted function to assign a default value but that did not work. It will be hard to define all these in a static data as then I have to know all the tests before the rest call.

Looking at the [Vue warning when accessing nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52751705/vue-warning-when-accessing-nested-object)  the issue is if I do the check for inside
the checkbox (Checkbox is rendered from Spring MVC tag).

```
 <form:checkbox id="xx" path="..Spring MVC Path.."   v-if="(xx.xx.abc.tests!=null && xx.xxx.abc.tests[3].selected)" **v-model**="xx.xxx.abc.tests[3].selected"/>
```

The checkbox does not appear at all. I want it to appear regardless of empty value as it gives users to add the option. Also, the other option of statically declaring it does not work as I don't know want to hard code and define array.
for example that means in case another element is added it is hardcoded into script:
  [
     {
         "testName": String,
         "result": String,
          "selected": false,
          "comment": String
       },
       {
        "testName": String,
        "result": String,
        "selected": false,
        "comment": String
    }
]

Basically I need to bind using v-model even if it is null in this case. Tried Vue.set but for some reason did not appear to work.

I guess I am missing something here,any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue warning when accessing nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52751705/vue-warning-when-accessing-nested-object). From the accepted answer, see option #2 - Conditional Rendering

Comment: thanks Phil, but does not really answer my case, I edited it for more information..

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a list of checkbox to render whether the child element is null on not. but you do know the array length, right? 
If you do, consider use v-for to render checkboxes (then you’re able to track array item by index) and listening on its change event then assign specific value to specific object when events fire

Comment: bit different use case, although I know the array length, using v-for is not the best here as it has other sub elements you will need to render. for example, checking another checkbox will drive makes some other checkboxes or selects appear. There is no need to do a fully dynamic UI in this isnatnce as it will make it quite harder. There are business rules on what drives what. So, trying to do with v-for and in the loop coding all logic as rendering child elements depending on what rules will make to very complex.  Could you bind to the model after the element is rendered?

Comment: Could you give a live demo base on the business rules so we can see what the it really required? It's quite ambiguous to understand the use case. What would the array look like in real cases ? Could it be nested?  Do you need to render a fixed number of checkboxes or it depends on the array length ?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies. As this was due to rest call not returning all required attributes that was defined in Vue model(As mentioned in question).So I checked that in final section of rest call and if they are empty, created them.

```html
axios
                .get(***URL***)
                .then(
                    response => {
                        this.info = response.data;
                        this.status.loaded = true;
                    }
                )
               
                .finally(
                    () => {
                        *** check and fill missing attributes with default values ***
                        **Example: this.$set(this.someObject, 'b', 2)
                    }
                )
```

Reference:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html