# VueJs passing empty Prop Object to sub component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have a UserProfile component with data as follows that works fine:

```js
export default {
  name: 'UserProfile',
  data () {
    return {
      user: {}
    }
  },
...
```

I have a subcomponent UserItems that I want to call with a prop for `this.user`

like:

```html
<UserItems :user="this.user" \>
```

When I hardcode `this.user` as {id:1}, everything works downstream

However, otherwise, UserItems component is receiving an empty object.

Here is my UserItems component:

```html
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <NewItem  v-on:item-created="getOwnedItems(user.id)" />
      <h6 class="text-muted mt-3">Your Items:</h6> 
      <ul class="list-group">
        <Item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="`${i}-${item.id} `" :item="item" v-on:item-deleted="getOwnedItems"/>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Item from "@/components/Items/Item";
import NewItem from "@/components/Items/NewItem";

export default {
  name: "UserItems",
  props: {
    user: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  components: {
    Item,
    NewItem
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getOwnedItems();
  },
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.$store.state.ownedItems;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getOwnedItems () {
      console.log('getting owned items')
      console.log('this.user is: ', this.user)
      this.$store.dispatch("getOwnedItems", this.user.id);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This is the axios request:

```
fetchOwnedItems (params) {
    console.log('services params is: ', params)
    return axios.get('items/by_user/' + params)
  },
```

This is the express route:

```
router.get('/by_user/:id', auth.required, async (req, res) => {
  console.log('this is params on getOwned items', req.params)
  const items = await Item
    .query()
    .where('users_id', req.params.id)
    .orderBy('title');
  res.json(items);
});
```

The Vue console shows:
`this.user is:  {__ob__: Observer}`

How do I pass the same User from UserProfile?

Comment: Sounds like your `user` data is loaded asynchronously. Try [conditional rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html), ie `<UserItems v-if="user && user.id" :user="user"/>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue warning when accessing nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52751705/vue-warning-when-accessing-nested-object)

Comment: adding the if statement seems to solve the problem of undefined this.user. so in ItemsService, the console.log returns the correct user.  however, by the time it gets to the express side, req params is empty.

Comment: @Phil Both of these comments helped immensely. This is working now after adjusting the vuex action.  if you make this an answer, I will accept. Thanks!